# Is FireFox caching jquery.ajax returns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function that uses jquery.ajax to test whether a file is there or not, on an URL.
The function is called by an IF statement that returns `Ok it exists` if the file is up there or `it doesn't exist`, to an ID into the wabpage itself.

With Chrome and IE this works fine.
With FF, it returns always `it doesn't exist` and not errors are generated in console.

```
function UrlExists(urlCheck){
        var http = jQuery.ajax({
            type:"HEAD", //Not get
            url: urlCheck,
            async: false
        });
        return http.status!=404;
}

var urlToCheck = "https://example.org/filetocheck.txt";
if(UrlExists(urlToCheck)){
    $('#exists').html("Ok it exists");
} else {
    $('#exists').html("it doesn't exist");
}
```

Thinking to cache, I send the following headers, when the page is called
without solving the issue

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Needless to say that CTRL+F5 doesn't work either.

is there anything I can do in order to get it working on FF as well?

Thanks in advance

**[EDIT]**
Both the answers of @JonasGrumann and @Umar_ are working fine
**[/EDIT]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a timestamp to the url should trick the browser into thinking it's a new URL, so that it will ignore the cache:

```
function UrlExists(urlCheck){
    var http = jQuery.ajax({
        type:"HEAD", //Not get
        url: urlCheck,
        async: false
    });
    return http.status!=404;
}
var d=new Date();
var urlToCheck = "https://example.org/filetocheck.txt?t=" + d.getTime();
if(UrlExists(urlToCheck)){
    $('#exists').html("Ok it exists");
} else {
    $('#exists').html("it doesn't exist");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `cache` property of jQuery Ajax as `false` to prevent this.

```
function UrlExists(urlCheck){
    var http = jQuery.ajax({
        type:"HEAD", //Not get
        url: urlCheck,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
    });
    return http.status!=404; }
```